# How to convert table data to Excel format in an Entity Framework project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework project, I have tables named

- dbo.patient
- dbo.doctor
- dbo.disease

These three tables are interconnected.

I need to convert the patient data with doctor name and disease name into an Excel format file... what do I have to do to accomplish this?

I have no idea how to do it...

Can anyone provide steps?

Should I create a stored procedure? How to convert data to Excel format?

Can I do it without using a stored procedure?

Comment: You need to solve two problems: **(1)** retrieving the correct data - using a proper EF query, that should be fairly trivial, and then **(2)** convert that data into a file that can be read by Excel - you need to find a suitable **library** for that, don't try to do this yourself - too much work. There's tons of Excel writing libraries for C# that will help you - just Google or Bing!

Comment: if i have a library, in which part should i have to  concentrate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **free and opensource** library called **EPPlus** for that.

Here is the Link : 
[**EPPlus-Create advanced Excel spreadsheets**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)

Here is how to do that ..

**Step 1 :**

Run following command on the Package Manager console :

***PM > install-package epplus***

**Step 2 :**

This is the method for exporting data :

**Note :** You can replace the `data` with your `actual data` after retrieving it from the server by using EF query.

```
public void ExportListUsingEPPlus()
       {
           //this is the data retrieval point you have to replace with your data
           var data = new[]{ 
              new{ Name="Myname", Email="myna@google.com"},
              new{ Name="yourname", Email="your@yahoo.com"},
              new{ Name="saman", Email="saman@yahoo.com"},
           };
 
           ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
           var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
           workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, true);
           using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
               Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Contact.xlsx");
               excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
               memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
               Response.Flush();
               Response.End();
           }
       }
```

Comment: The link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can export data in html or csv format and let Excel do the conversion. This has it's own pitfalls.

For example, with csv, if you have text data that looks like a date or a number, Excel will convert it to a date or a number. When this might happen, I put a tab character into the data to stop it.

And, with html, if you tell the browser that it should be opened using Excel, the user gets a warning that the format isn't Excel.

Nonetheless, I have used these techniques to do simple exports in my MVC application without resorting to a library.

To set the response to Excel (for html output):

```
protected void SetResponseToExcel(string fileName)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
      "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
}
```

To set the response to csv:

```
protected void SetResponseToText(string fileName)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
       "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
}
```

To do the export:

```
   public ActionResult MyExport()
   {
        SetResponseToText("MyFilename.csv");
        Response.Write(String.Format("\"{0}\",...,{26}",
           "Heading 1", ..., Environment.NewLine));
        Response.Flush();

        IEnumerable<MyClass> exportData = _MyService.GetMyData();
        foreach (var row in exportData)
        {
            Response.Write(String.Format("\"{0}\"...,{26}",
                "\t" + row.Field1, //tab character to force Excel to treat it as text
                 row.Field2, ..., Environment.NewLine));
        }
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return null;
    }
```